# why onchange event not fire in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-schema-form

I am making a form from json .i am using **angular-schema-form** with dependancy in **tv4.js**.I study from this 
https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#global-options
That we can apply onchange went on element .but when I apply it not call it also not giving any error why ?
Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/wbziK5aRUg69JuwXDoVy?p=preview

```
onChange: function(modelValue,form) {
      console.log("Password is",modelValue);
    }
```

I used like that

```
"email": {
            "title": "Email",
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 2,
            "pattern": "^\\S+@\\S+$",
            onChange: function(modelValue,form) {
      console.log("Password is"+modelValue);
          },
            validationMessage: {
              200: "Address is too short, man.",
              "default": "Just write a proper address, will you?" //Special catch all error message
            },
            "description": "Email will be used for evil.",
            required: true
          },
```

is there problem in binding ?

Answer (score 1):

You added onChange in a wrong place. it should be not in schema but in form. check this one http://plnkr.co/edit/h02XKqF3Vc6eefTOEN8m?p=preview

```
 $scope.form = [
        "name",
        "student",
        {
          key: "email",
          onChange: function(modelValue, form) {
            console.log("email changed");
            console.debug(modelValue);
            console.debug(form);
          }
        },
        "title",
        {
          type: "submit",
          title: "Save"
        }
      ];
```

Though for email field event is not triggered until you enter valid value. not sure if it should work like that.

You're also missing angular-schema-form tag because this question is related to that particular library.

BR

Answer (score 1):

I had a look on the sfChanged directive. Unfortunately...

I didn't want to spend a lot of time to just bind a change event.
Maybe this tool is not serious...

To plug the change event logic, on your html form object ensure that:

`ng-model (add to sf-model, sf-schema, sf-form)`

is bound on the model form, example:

`ng-model="modelForm" (sf-Model="modelForm")`

On your HTML form object ensure that `sf-changed` attribute exists 
with this syntax:

`sf-changed="onChange"`

On the schema object, for the key you want to bind a change event, write:

```
{
  key: "yourkey",
  ...blabla...waouou...
  x-schema-form: {
    onChange: function () { console.log('now it runs'); }
 }  
}
```

I debugged the sfChanged directive, and now your change event is triggered.

Alone on the form object your change event is not recognized.

The 'on blur option' runs personally and I discover the tool and I cry "why me?" "why so much hate?"

The documentation has a big hole, have a nice day.