# how to get event of on change of drop down in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

can you please tell me how to get event of on change of drop down in angular ?.
I make a drop down from json .I need to show alert when user change the drop down **ng:change** and get it drop down value ? I make form form using this doc
https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#global-options

here is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/wbziK5aRUg69JuwXDoVy?p=preview
how I i bind **ng:change** ?
here is my drop down

```
 title: {
            type: "string",
            required: true,
            enum: ['dr', 'jr', 'sir', 'mrs', 'mr', 'NaN', 'dj']
          }
```

how to bind the drop down event ?

Comment: I think you are again asking your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336417/why-onchange-event-not-fire-in-angular-js

Comment: Since when is NaN a title? ;)

Comment: yes but it is different than that Qusestion because now i need to bind drop down..but i think concept is same

Comment: @ThiefMaster i just take a simple example from documentation

Comment: @ThiefMaster do you have any solution ?

Answer (score -2):

[angularjs Select with filter to filter out the option that's already selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851504/angularjs-select-with-filter-to-filter-out-the-option-thats-already-selected/12851597#12851597)

refer this you need to use ng options and you r using array.and ur trying to populate object thats why it is not getting binded i guess

Comment: so what is the solution ? have you see th documentation.can you please the my plunker

Comment: what is ng change function here in plunker?